# SSRS Report Subscriptions: How can I tell when a recipient in a subscription was sent the SSRS report?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

How can I tell when a recipient in a subscription was sent the SSRS report?

I've seen similar questions but they seem to relate to which email addresses are currently subscribed to the report, rather than specific instances of when an email was sent to the recipient(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this SQL script to find the execution log of subscriptions.

There are some example reports in my [GitHub project](https://github.com/SQL-Server-projects/Reporting-Services-examples).

```
USE [ReportServer];
GO

DECLARE @StartDate      DATETIME = '03-MAR-2022';
DECLARE @EndDate        DATETIME = '04-MAR-2022';
DECLARE @ReportFolder   NVARCHAR(200) = NULL;
DECLARE @ReportName     NVARCHAR(200) = NULL;
DECLARE @LogStatus      NVARCHAR(200) = NULL;
DECLARE @StatusGroup    NVARCHAR(200) = NULL;
DECLARE @ServiceAccount NVARCHAR(200) = 'your_service_account';  -- enter the subscription service account here

WITH
report_status
AS
(
   SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
    ( 'rrRenderingError', 'Failure')
   , ( 'rsHttpRuntimeClientDisconnectionError', 'Failure')
   , ( 'rsInternalError', 'Failure')
   , ( 'rsInvalidDataSourceCredentialSetting', 'Failure')
   , ( 'rsProcessingAborted', 'Failure')
   , ( 'rsProcessingError', 'Failure')
   , ( 'rsRenderingExtensionNotFound', 'Failure')
   , ( 'rsReportServerDatabaseError', 'Failure')
   , ( 'rsSuccess', 'Success')
   ) tbl ([StatusName], [StatusGroup]) 
)
,
report_users 
AS
(
   SELECT 
        [UserID]
       , [UserName]
       , [SimpleUserName] = LOWER(RIGHT([UserName], (LEN([UserName]) - CHARINDEX('\', [UserName]))))
   FROM 
      [dbo].[Users] WITH(NOLOCK)
)
, 
report_catalog
AS
(
    SELECT    
         rpt.[ItemID]
        , rpt.[CreatedById]
        , rpt.[ModifiedById]
        , rpt.[Type]
        , rpt.[Name] 
        , [ReportName] = rpt.[Name] 
        , rpt.[Description]
        , rpt.[Parameter]
        , [CreationDate] = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), rpt.[CreationDate], 13))
        , [ModifiedDate] = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), rpt.[ModifiedDate], 13))
        , [ReportFolder] = SUBSTRING(rpt.[Path], 2, Len(rpt.[Path])-Len(rpt.[Name])-2) 
        , rpt.[Path]
        , [URL_ReportFolder] = 'http://' + Host_Name() + '/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2f'  + SUBSTRING(rpt.[Path], 2, Len(rpt.[Path])-Len(rpt.[Name])-2)  + '&ViewMode=List'
        , [URL_Report] = 'http://' + Host_Name() + '/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2f'  + SUBSTRING(rpt.[Path], 2, Len(rpt.[Path])-Len(rpt.[Name])-2)  + '%2f' + rpt.[Name]
        , [ReportDefinition] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), rpt.[Content]))  
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Catalog] AS rpt WITH (NOLOCK) 
    WHERE 
        1=1
        AND rpt.[Type] = 2
)
,
subscription_days
AS
(
   SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 'DaysOfMonth', 1, '1')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 2, '2')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 4, '3')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 8, '4')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 16, '5')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 32, '6')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 64, '7')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 128, '8')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 256, '9')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 512, '10')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 1024, '11')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 2048, '12')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 4096, '13')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 8192, '14')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 16384, '15')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 32768, '16')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 65536, '17')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 131072, '18')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 262144, '19')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 524288, '20')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 1048576, '21')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 2097152, '22')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 4194304, '23')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 8388608, '24')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 16777216, '25')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 33554432, '26')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 67108864, '27')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 134217728, '28')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 268435456, '29')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 536870912, '30')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 1073741824, '31')
      , ( 'DaysOfMonth', 8193, '1st and 14th')
      , ( 'DaysOfWeek', 1, 'Sun')
      , ( 'DaysOfWeek', 2, 'Mon')
      , ( 'DaysOfWeek', 4, 'Tues')
      , ( 'DaysOfWeek', 8, 'Wed')
      , ( 'DaysOfWeek', 16, 'Thurs')
      , ( 'DaysOfWeek', 32, 'Fri')
      , ( 'DaysOfWeek', 64, 'Sat')
      , ( 'DaysOfWeek', 62, 'Mon - Fri')
      , ( 'DaysOfWeek', 10, 'Mon - Wed')
      , ( 'DaysOfWeek', 24, 'Wed - Thurs')
      , ( 'DaysOfWeek', 120, 'Wed - Sat')
      , ( 'DaysOfWeek', 126, 'Mon - Sat')
      , ( 'DaysOfWeek', 127, 'Daily')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 1, 'Sun')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 127, 'Sun')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 2, 'Mon')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 10, 'Mon')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 62, 'Mon')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 126, 'Mon')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 127, 'Mon')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 4, 'Tue')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 10, 'Tue')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 62, 'Tue')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 126, 'Tue')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 127, 'Tue')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 8, 'Wed')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 10, 'Wed')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 24, 'Wed')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 62, 'Wed')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 120, 'Wed')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 126, 'Wed')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 127, 'Wed')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 16, 'Thr')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 24, 'Thr')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 62, 'Thr')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 120, 'Thr')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 126, 'Thr')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 127, 'Thr')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 32, 'Fri')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 62, 'Fri')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 120, 'Fri')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 126, 'Fri')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 127, 'Fri')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 64, 'Sat')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 120, 'Sat')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 126, 'Sat')
      , ( 'DayOfWeek', 127, 'Sat')
   ) tbl ([GroupName], [CodeNbr], [Label])
)
,
subscription_schedule
AS
(
   SELECT
        [ScheduleID]
      , [SchDaySun] = Sun
      , [SchDayMon] = Mon
      , [SchDayTue] = Tue
      , [SchDayWed] = Wed
      , [SchDayThr] = Thr
      , [SchDayFri] = Fri
      , [SchDaySat] = Sat
      , [ScheduleName]
      , [ScheduleStartDate]
      , [ScheduleEndDate]
      , [Flags]
      , [RecurrenceType]
      , [State]
      , [MinutesInterval]
      , [DaysInterval]
      , [WeeksInterval]
      , [DaysOfWeek]
      , [DaysOfMonth]
      , [Month]
      , [MonthlyWeek]
      , [ScheduleDays]
   FROM
   (
      SELECT
           sc.[ScheduleID]
         , sd.[CodeNbr]
         , sd.[Label]
         , [ScheduleName] = CASE WHEN sc.[EventType] = 'SharedSchedule' THEN sc.[name] ELSE NULL END
         , [ScheduleStartDate] = sc.[StartDate]
         , [ScheduleEndDate] = sc.[EndDate]
         , sc.[Flags]
         , sc.[RecurrenceType]
         , sc.[State]
         , sc.[MinutesInterval]
         , sc.[DaysInterval]
         , sc.[WeeksInterval]
         , sc.[DaysOfWeek]
         , sc.[DaysOfMonth]
         , sc.[Month]
         , sc.[MonthlyWeek]
         , [ScheduleDays] =
            CASE
                WHEN sc.[DaysOfMonth] IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(dom.[Label], '(' + CAST(sc.[DaysOfMonth] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ') NOT CODED')
                WHEN sc.[DaysOfWeek] IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(dow.[Label], '(' + CAST(sc.[DaysOfWeek] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ') NOT CODED')
            END
      FROM
         [dbo].[Schedule] sc WITH (NOLOCK) 
         LEFT JOIN subscription_days sd ON sc.[DaysOfWeek] = sd.[CodeNbr] AND sd.[GroupName] = 'DayOfWeek'
         LEFT JOIN subscription_days AS dom ON sc.[DaysOfMonth] = dom.[CodeNbr] AND dom.[GroupName] = 'DaysOfMonth'
         LEFT JOIN subscription_days AS dow ON sc.[DaysOfWeek] = dow.[CodeNbr] AND dow.[GroupName] = 'DaysOfWeek'
   ) sch
   PIVOT
   (
      COUNT(sch.[Label])
      FOR sch.[Label]
      IN ([Sun], [Mon], [Tue], [Wed], [Thr], [Fri], [Sat])
   ) AS pvt
)
,
report_subscription
AS
(
   SELECT
      sub.[SubscriptionID]
      , sub.[Report_OID]
      , [SubscriptionDescription] = sub.[Description]
      , sub.[ExtensionSettings]
      , sub.[EventType]
      , sub.[OwnerID]
      , sub.[ModifiedByID]
      , sub.[ModifiedDate]
      , [RunTime] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), sub.[LastRunTime], 8)
      , [LastRunDate] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), sub.[LastRunTime], 13)
      , [LastRunTime] = CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(16), sub.[LastRunTime], 113) AS DATETIME)
      , sub.[DeliveryExtension]
      , sub.[MatchData]
      , [SubscriptionLastStatus] = sub.[LastStatus]
      , [StatusFail] = CASE WHEN sub.[LastStatus] LIKE '%Mail sent%' THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END
      , [EmailSubject] = CASE CHARINDEX('<Name>SUBJECT</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE SUBSTRING(sub.ExtensionSettings, LEN('<Name>SUBJECT</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>SUBJECT</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings), CHARINDEX('</Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings, CHARINDEX('<Name>SUBJECT</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings) + 1) - (LEN('<Name>SUBJECT</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>SUBJECT</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings))) END
      , [EmailTo] = SUBSTRING(sub.ExtensionSettings, LEN('<Name>TO</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>TO</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings), CHARINDEX('</Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings, CHARINDEX('<Name>TO</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings) + 1) - (LEN('<Name>TO</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>TO</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings)))
      , [EmailCc] = CASE CHARINDEX('<Name>CC</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE SUBSTRING(sub.ExtensionSettings, LEN('<Name>CC</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>CC</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings), CHARINDEX('</Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings, CHARINDEX('<Name>CC</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings) + 1) - (LEN('<Name>CC</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>CC</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings))) END
      , [EmailBcc] = CASE CHARINDEX('<Name>BCC</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE SUBSTRING(sub.ExtensionSettings, LEN('<Name>BCC</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>BCC</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings), CHARINDEX('</Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings, CHARINDEX('<Name>BCC</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings) + 1) - (LEN('<Name>BCC</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>BCC</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings))) END
      , [EmailComment] = CASE CHARINDEX('<Name>Comment</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE SUBSTRING(sub.ExtensionSettings, LEN('<Name>Comment</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>Comment</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings), CHARINDEX('</Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings, CHARINDEX('<Name>Comment</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings) + 1) - (LEN('<Name>Comment</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>Comment</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings))) END
      , [EmailIncludeLink] = CASE CHARINDEX('<Name>IncludeLink</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE SUBSTRING(sub.ExtensionSettings, LEN('<Name>IncludeLink</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>IncludeLink</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings), CHARINDEX('</Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings, CHARINDEX('<Name>IncludeLink</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings) + 1) - (LEN('<Name>IncludeLink</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>IncludeLink</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings))) END
      , [EmailRenderFormat] = CASE CHARINDEX('<Name>RenderFormat</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE SUBSTRING(sub.ExtensionSettings, LEN('<Name>RenderFormat</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>RenderFormat</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings), CHARINDEX('</Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings, CHARINDEX('<Name>RenderFormat</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings) + 1) - (LEN('<Name>RenderFormat</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>RenderFormat</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings))) END
      , [EmailPriority] = CASE CHARINDEX('<Name>Priority</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings) WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE SUBSTRING(sub.ExtensionSettings, LEN('<Name>Priority</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>Priority</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings), CHARINDEX('</Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings, CHARINDEX('<Name>Priority</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings) + 1) - (LEN('<Name>Priority</Name><Value>') + CHARINDEX('<Name>Priority</Name><Value>', sub.ExtensionSettings))) END
      , sch.[MinutesInterval]
      , sch.[DaysInterval]
      , sch.[WeeksInterval]
      , sch.[DaysOfWeek]
      , sch.[DaysOfMonth]
      , sch.[Month]
      , sch.[MonthlyWeek]
      , sch.[ScheduleName]
      , sch.[ScheduleDays]
      , sch.[SchDaySun]
      , sch.[SchDayMon]
      , sch.[SchDayTue]
      , sch.[SchDayWed]
      , sch.[SchDayThr]
      , sch.[SchDayFri]
      , sch.[SchDaySat]
      , sch.[ScheduleStartDate]
      , sch.[ScheduleEndDate]
      , sch.[Flags]
      , sch.[RecurrenceType]
      , sch.[State]
      , sub.[LastStatus]
      , rs.[ScheduleID]
   FROM
      [dbo].[Subscriptions] AS sub WITH (NOLOCK) 
      LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Notifications] AS n WITH (NOLOCK) ON n.[SubscriptionID] = sub.[SubscriptionID] AND sub.[Report_OID] = n.[ReportID]
      LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ReportSchedule] AS rs WITH (NOLOCK) ON sub.[SubscriptionID] = rs.[SubscriptionID]
      LEFT JOIN subscription_schedule AS sch ON rs.[ScheduleID] = sch.[ScheduleID]
)
SELECT 
    rpt.[Path]
   , rpt.[ReportFolder]
   , rpt.[Name]
   , rpt.[URL_ReportFolder]
   , rpt.[URL_Report]
   , [URL_Report_Filtered] = rpt.URL_Report + '&rs:Command=Render&' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2000), el.[Parameters])
   , [UserName] = usr.[SimpleUserName]
   , el.[Status]
   , el.[TimeStart]
   , el.[RowCount]
   , el.[ByteCount]
   , el.[Format]
   , [Parameters] = 
      REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
      REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), el.[Parameters])
      , '%20', ' ')
      , '%2F', '-')
      , '%3C', '<')
      , '%3E', '>')
      , '%3A', ':')
   , [TotalSeconds] = CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(ms, (el.[TimeDataRetrieval] + el.[TimeProcessing] + el.[TimeRendering]), 0), 108)
   , [TimeDataRetrieval] = CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(ms, el.[TimeDataRetrieval], 0), 108) 
   , [TimeProcessing] = CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(ms, el.[TimeProcessing], 0), 108)  
   , [TimeRendering] = CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(ms, el.[TimeRendering], 0), 108) 
   , [SubscriptionOwner] = usc.[SimpleUserName]
   , [SubscriptionModifiedBy] = usm.[SimpleUserName]
   , [SubscriptionModifiedDate] = sub.[ModifiedDate]
   , sub.[SubscriptionID]
   , sub.[SubscriptionDescription]
   , sub.[ExtensionSettings]
   , sub.[EventType]
   , sub.[EmailSubject]
   , sub.[EmailTo]
   , sub.[EmailCc]
   , sub.[EmailBcc]
   , sub.[EmailComment]
   , sub.[EmailIncludeLink]
   , sub.[EmailRenderFormat]
   , sub.[EmailPriority]
   , sub.[DeliveryExtension]
   , [DeliveryExtensionImage] = 
       CASE 
          WHEN sub.[DeliveryExtension] = 'Report Server Email' THEN 'email'
          WHEN sub.[DeliveryExtension] = 'Report Server FileShare' THEN 'folder'
          ELSE sub.[DeliveryExtension]
       END
   , sub.[SubscriptionLastStatus]
   , sub.[StatusFail]
   , sub.[MatchData]
   , sub.[RunTime]
   , sub.[LastRunDate]
   , sub.[LastRunTime]
   , sub.[MinutesInterval]
   , sub.[DaysInterval]
   , sub.[WeeksInterval]
   , sub.[DaysOfWeek]
   , sub.[DaysOfMonth]
   , sub.[Month]
   , sub.[MonthlyWeek]
   , sub.[ScheduleName]
   , sub.[ScheduleDays]
   , sub.[SchDaySun]
   , sub.[SchDayMon]
   , sub.[SchDayTue]
   , sub.[SchDayWed]
   , sub.[SchDayThr]
   , sub.[SchDayFri]
   , sub.[SchDaySat]
   , sub.[ScheduleStartDate]
   , sub.[ScheduleEndDate]
   , sub.[Flags]
   , sub.[RecurrenceType]
   , sub.[State]
   , [EventStatus] = el.[Status]
   , [EventDateTime] = el.[TimeEnd]
   , sub.[LastStatus]
   , sub.[ScheduleID]
FROM 
   report_catalog AS rpt 
   INNER JOIN report_subscription AS sub ON sub.[Report_OID] = rpt.[ItemID]
   LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ExecutionLog] AS el WITH (NOLOCK) ON el.[ReportID] = rpt.[ItemID]
   LEFT JOIN report_status AS rs ON el.[Status] = rs.[StatusName]
   LEFT JOIN report_users AS usr ON el.[UserName] = usr.[UserName]
   LEFT JOIN report_users AS usc ON sub.[OwnerID] = usc.[UserID]
   LEFT JOIN report_users AS usm ON sub.[ModifiedByID] = usm.[UserID]
WHERE 
    1=1
    AND (@StartDate IS NULL OR el.[TimeStart] >= @StartDate)
    AND (@EndDate IS NULL OR el.[TimeStart] <= @EndDate)    
    AND (@ReportFolder IS NULL OR rpt.[ReportFolder] = @ReportFolder)
    AND (@ReportName IS NULL OR rpt.[ReportName] = @ReportName)
    AND (@LogStatus IS NULL OR el.[Status] = @LogStatus)
    AND (@StatusGroup IS NULL OR rs.[StatusGroup] = @StatusGroup)
    AND (@ServiceAccount IS NULL OR usr.[SimpleUserName] = @ServiceAccount)
ORDER BY 
    rpt.[Path]
   , el.[TimeStart] DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. You made my day 

Comment: No worries, anytime. Can you click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to accept the answer?